How can I use pug in angular esbuild, using @angular-builders/custom-esbuild
I am using angular 17, I use pug template, current, I use ng-cli-pug-loader to load pug.
I want to transfer to esbuild, so after researching I know that esbuild can config plugin. Can I use plugin to help me load and render pug file in angular project.
I try to create  custom plugin, but it doesn't work, I just can load pug file, but can't render pug to html.
Someone told me use @angular-builders/custom-esbuild, but I stuck when find solution with it.
